# unserialize() multiple select values in multi select tag with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have select tag having multiple attribute in it from which I am saving multiple values in the database using PHP `serialize` function as serialized array:

Database array which I am inserting:

```
a:9:{i:0;s:8:"Arkansas";i:1;s:10:"California";i:2;s:8:"Delaware";i:3;s:7:"Montana";i:4;s:14:"North Carolina";i:5;s:12:"North Dakota";i:6;s:8:"Nebraska";i:7;s:13:"New Hampshire";i:8;s:10:"New Jersey";}
```

Now I want to show these selected values in my `SELECT` dropdown with `SELECTED` attribute for the values in my database rest will show as it is non selected.

**Example:** I have **states** table and I have selected **New York, Miami** and save them to database as **serialized array**. Now, on edit page I want to show **New York, Miami** as selected while rest states will show as it is non selected.

Here is the code which I am working on:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `web_states`") or die (mysqli_error());
        $menu   = "<select name='jurisdiction_state[]' class='multiselectState' id='focusedInput' multiple='multiple' size='15' required>";
        $author = unserialize($data);
        foreach( $author as $index=>$key ) {
        $authorRecs = $this->getStateData($key);
        $Recs   = $authorRecs->fetch_object();
        $menu   .= "<option value='".$Recs->state_name."' selected=selected'>".$Recs->state_name."</option>";
        }  
        $menu   .=  "</select>";
        echo $menu;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it myself and now the problem is resolved. From my previous code that was not possible.

Here is the serilized array from the database:

```
a:9:{i:0;s:8:"Arkansas";i:1;s:10:"California";i:2;s:8:"Delaware";i:3;s:7:"Montana";i:4;s:14:"North Carolina";i:5;s:12:"North Dakota";i:6;s:8:"Nebraska";i:7;s:13:"New Hampshire";i:8;s:10:"New Jersey";}
```

I simply unserialize it using:

```
$data = unserialize(a:9:{i:0;s:8:"Arkansas";i:1;s:10:"California";i:2;s:8:"Delaware";i:3;s:7:"Montana";i:4;s:14:"North Carolina";i:5;s:12:"North Dakota";i:6;s:8:"Nebraska";i:7;s:13:"New Hampshire";i:8;s:10:"New Jersey";})
```

and get the 1st index of that array which returns `State Names` in the form of array.

So finally I have used `in_array()` to check the selected and non selected and got the final result.

Here is the working code.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT state_name FROM `web_states`") or die (mysqli_error());

$menu   = "<select name='jurisdiction_state[]' class='multiselectState' id='focusedInput' multiple='multiple' size='15' required>";

$author[1] = unserialize($data);

while($rcData = $result->fetch_array()){

if(in_array($rcData['state_name'], $author[1])){

$menu .=  "<option value='".$rcData['state_name']."' selected='selected'>".$rcData['state_name']."</option>";

}else{

$menu .=  "<option value='".$rcData['state_name']."'>".$rcData['state_name']."</option>";

    }
}
$menu .=  "</select>";
echo $menu;
```

Hope it helps someone.